# C - MPI: how to transpose a pseudo-2D array, already scattered across processes?

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I reached a point in my code-development at which a vector called `arr` of length `(N_r * N_theta * N_phi)` which "represents" a 3D tensor called `ten` of shape `(N_rs, N_thetas, N_phis)` is split across processes as follows: each process has a given set of `i`-indices, and all the 2nd and the 3rd dimensions. As below:

- process 0 has `ten[i, :, :]` for i = 0, i = 1, i = 2, ... i = i_f0
- process 1 has `ten[i, :, :]` for i = i_f0 + 1 , i = i_f0 + 2, ... , i = i_f1
- etc...

The 2nd and 3rd dimensions are stored continuously in memory, in C-order (last index varies the fastest). As one would expect.

I now need to perform some MPI magic to arrive at the following:

- process 0 has `ten[:, L, M]` for (L, M) = (0, 0), (L, M) = (0, 1), ..., (L, M) = (L_f0, M_f0)
- process 1 has `ten[:, L, M]` for (L, M) = (L_f0, M_f0 + 1), (L, M) = (L_f0, M_f0 + 2), ..., (L, M) = (L_f1, M_f1)
- etc ...

I feel I need to use MPI Derived Datatypes. Correct?

I have thus read about `MPI_Type_vector`.

I feel I need to use `MPI_Alltoall`. Correct?

**Question**: How could I use a custom-made derived datatype in the Alltoall communication?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see why you'll have to use MPI Derived Datatype, `MPI_Type_vector` for this. For every (L,M) you need to retrieve `ten[:,L,M]`. Well with an index I for the first dimension, for I=0,...,i_f0 recv ten[I,L,M] from 0, then for I=i_f0+1,...,i_f1, recv ten[I,L,M] from 1 etc...